How to get a <Message> to appear in the Error List in Visual Studio?
I have added to my project the following task:
<Target Name="Foo" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Some text." />
</Target>

The message appears in the Output window, but not in the Error List window.
Is there a way to do that?
I checked other questions that deal with the Error List and I'm not very optimistic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/warning-task?view=vs-2022

You can add Warning tasks to your project.
here is an example:
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="ValidateCommandLine">
    <Warning
        Text=" The 0 property was not set on the command line."
        Condition="'$(0)' == ''" />
    <Warning
        Text=" The FREEBUILD property was not set on the command line."
        Condition="'$(FREEBUILD)' == ''" />
</Target>
...

Please be aware that Warning tasks can only be executed before the build process.
